# How to inherit type-based styles in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to use the same style for all `Image`s and `AutoGreyableImage`s (my custom control that inherits from `Image`).  I have the following style declared application-wide:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}"
    x:Key="ImageType">
    <Setter Property="Stretch"
            Value="Uniform" />
    <Setter Property="Height"
            Value="16" />
    <Setter Property="Width"
            Value="16" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
            Value="True" />
</Style>
```

But the `AutoGreyableImage`s don't accept the style.  This doesn't work either:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type my:AutoGreyableImage}"
       BasedOn="{DynamicResource ImageType}" />
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a StaticResource reference in the dependent style.

Try this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type my:AutoGreyableImage}" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource ImageType}" />
```

Answer (score 3):

It works fine for me.

*AutoGreyableImage.cs*:

```
public class AutoGreyableImage : Image
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CustomProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Custom",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(AutoGreyableImage));

    public string Custom
    {
        get { return GetValue(CustomProperty) as string; }
        set { SetValue(CustomProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

*Window.xaml*:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Image" x:Key="ImageStyle">
        <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Uniform"/>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:AutoGreyableImage}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ImageStyle}">
        <Setter Property="Custom" Value="Hello"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="30"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <local:AutoGreyableImage Source="C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\My Pictures\Sample Pictures\Winter.jpg"/>
</Grid>
```