# Exception from custom control in WPF app

Tags: wpf, xaml, custom-controls

I'm trying to create custom control for my WPF application and cant understand why its not working.

I have two projects - one is my custom control library with one custom control derived from `Image` with only few methods and the second project where I want to use my control. I dont want to do anything with styles or binding, so I'm using defaults.

So, my custom control theme (generic.xaml):

```
   <ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RTPlayer">
    <Style 
     TargetType="{x:Type local:RTPlayer}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Image}}">
    </Style>
```

And code part:

```
namespace RTPlayer
{
   public class RTPlayer : Image
   {
    static RTPlayer()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(RTPlayer), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(RTPlayer)));
    }

    public void Start()
    {
       // ....
    }
   }
}
```

In my main project I have added reference to my library .dll file and I'm trying to use control as:

```
  <Window x:Class="rtspWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:rtspWPF"
    xmlns:CustomControls="clr-namespace:RTPlayer;assembly=RTPlayer"
    xmlns:CustomControls="clr-namespace:RTPlayer;assembly=RTPlayer"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="auto" Width="auto">
<CustomControls:RTPlayer x:Name="image" Margin="10,10,10,10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  Width="auto" Height="auto"/>
```

The problems is - 1) xaml `CustomControl:RTPlayer` string warns me: "cant find resource named "System.Windows.Controls.Image". Resource names are case sensitive"; 2) If I'm trying to launch app its throw a `Markup.XamlParseException` that `Markup.StaticResourceHolder` throw exception..

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of `XamlParseException.InnerException`?

Comment: The Image Control doesn't have a base style you can inherit from in your Style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Daniel answer in comments, I have found out what I should do to make my app work.

After Daniel told me that  Image component doest not have a base style, I found a guy with simillar issue: [How to inherit type-based styles in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757185/how-to-inherit-type-based-styles-in-wpf)

Than I just rewrited my Generic.xaml file to this:

```
<ResourceDictionary
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RTPlayer">

   <Style TargetType="Image" x:Key="ImageStyle">

   </Style>

   <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:RTPlayer}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ImageStyle}">
   </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And everything worked!